# Rename a visual studio project under svn source control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have added two projects to my visual studio solution with  wrong names and committed to the svn repository. Now I want to correct  the name of the projects. How can I do that without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install Subversion integration plug-in such as AnkhSVN or VisualSVN and rename the solution, projects or any other items as you usually do through the Solution Explorer. Commit the change and don't forget to include an informative commit log message.